# VSCode json.schemas - run validator on command line

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsonschema

On my project, I use a [custom `json.schemas` validator](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json#_mapping-to-a-schema-in-the-workspace) like this:

```json
  "json.schemas": [
    {
      "fileMatch": ["src/super_jsons/**"],
      "url": "./.vscode/superJsonConfig.json"
    }
  ]
```

It works fine on my JSON files, adding autocomplete (IntelliSense) and inline validation of the allowed properties. You can see a [VSCode inline warning screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVJil.png) as an example.

My question is: How can I run this custom validator through the command line? Is it possible to integrate it with ESLint or something? My end goal is to integrate it on CI/CD to run during Pull Requests and log the warnings (or even mark them as errors).

Thank you

Comment: JSON Schema is a specification not specifically created for VSCode. There are many implementations - https://json-schema.org/implementations.html. Some of them work on the command line. You would need to work out a step use the config you've provided to power another CLI tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final solution was to use [ajv-cli](https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv-cli) and integrate it into our CI/CD.